# Need compatible version of x-pack-transport of org.elasticsearch.client with ElasticSearch 6.8.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We are using elasticsearch 6.8.2.
Existing code is using TrasportClient for connection with ElasticSearch from Java code.
Now there is ElastiSearch userid and password.
So we are trying to use x-pack-transport dependency of org.elasticsearch.client.
But not able to find compatible x-pack-transport version in maven repo.
Our application is using maven.

I am getting the following Exception for

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.put([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/elasticsearch/common/settings/Settings$Builder
```

In our POM

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code is

```
private Settings clientSettings() {
        return Settings.builder()
                .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true)
                .put("xpack.security.user", generateXPackSecurityUser())
                .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", "true")
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that they stopped publishing `x-pack-transport` on maven and instead suggest to use their own repository, you can find instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/setup-xpack-client.html).

However, they plan to sunset transport client and suggest to use http client instead:

> We plan on deprecating the TransportClient in Elasticsearch 7.0 and removing it completely in 8.0. Instead, you should be using the Java High Level REST Client, which executes HTTP requests rather than serialized Java requests.

The jar corresponding to the version 6.8.2 can be downloaded from [here](https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven/org/elasticsearch/client/x-pack-transport/6.8.2/x-pack-transport-6.8.2.jar).

Hope that helps!